# Why I am not seeing received money in my electrum?

Tags: electrum

The manual said that it will show up on history.

```
Status: 0/unconfirmed, broadcast through 4 nodes
Date: 10/26/2015 18:21
To: 19pHw8gbRP596CbiDdjNQbBrddAgQJ8pK2
Debit: -0.00956976 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00043024 BTC
Net amount: -0.01000000 BTC
Transaction ID: e816ada72c9b8940a67779825423bc473e3059fb5f9f5aab9d09ee19c636fa23-000
```

It didn't show up. Not even pending.

[image]

And I think I got the right address

[image]

Update: Transaction details changed. Now I got 71 confirmation. Still no money on electrum

e816ada72c9b8940a67779825423bc473e3059fb5f9f5aab9d09ee19c636fa23-000

Is there a refresh button or something? Is my electrum doesn't work.

Comment: Still not showing up. Is there a way to track what the problem is given that I have transaction id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. version 2.0.2 is very old. Before asking for help, please upgrade to the latest version.
2. if the issue persists, enter `wallet.clear_history()` in the electrum console, and restart electrum

Comment: That fixed the problem