# Electrum wallet shows zero balance

Tags: wallet, electrum, paper-wallet

I sent bitcoins to an offline (air gapped) electrum wallet.  I have blockchain.info proof the transaction took place and verification of the balance in the wallet (i used a watch only address to view balance and transaction history of offline wallet)  BUT electrum online wallet synchronizes but does not show updated balance information.  Electrum can find the funding transaction from the blockchain by the transaction id (Tools->Load transactions-From the blockchain)

Electrum 1.9.8
debian jessie (kali 2 sana)
via socks5 thru tor

resources consulted - none have a working fix

1.
[Why I am not seeing received money in my electrum?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41042/why-i-am-not-seeing-received-money-in-my-electrum#comment47223_41056)
wallet.clear_history() does not solve the problem for me

2.
https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/1525

3.
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1221590.msg12943509#msg12943509

Answer (score 1):

did you check that the offline wallet has the same addresses as the online wallet?

btw, please upgrade Electrum, version 1.9.8 is too old.